# Some android phone cannot search my app in android market

Tags: android, google-play

My app somehow cannot be searched by some of the model of mobile phone. like Sony Ericsson X10 mini pro, Samsung Galaxy. Is that the problem of resolution of the screen? How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on your settings in the Android Manifest, which displays / screen sizes you support; and of course different Android versions. And in case the devices are used in different countries/networks, it might also depends if you app is free/paid. Please post your AndroidManifest.xml.

You might have or have not a section in your manifest similar to this:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Are the devices running the same Android version?
Relevant section in the manifest might be this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mathias :
Here the link to support all screens : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Don't forget to test all screen size on the emulator.